# Writing SQL script that gets the list of all columns in BigQuery and injects them in query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table like this:

```
[ID]  [Country_Region]  [Date1]  [Date2]  [Date3] ... [Date150]
```

I wrote a SQL query in BigQuery that returns a dataset like this:

```
[ID] [Country_Region] [Date.ColumnName] [Date.Value] 
-----------------------------------------------------
 1    China           _1_22_20           12
 2    China           _1_23_20           34
 [3   China           _1_24_20           54] <----- I want this row and all the next ones to appear as well
```

My SQL query:

```
WITH timestamped_table AS 
(
    SELECT
        Country_Region,
        [STRUCT<timestamp STRING, timestamp_value INT64>
        ('2020-2-22', _2_22_20),
        ('2020-2-23', _2_23_20)] AS timestamp_data
    FROM
        `username.bq_timeseries_covid19.recovered_global` 
    WHERE
        Country_Region = 'China' AND Province_State = 'Zhejiang'
)
SELECT
    Country_Region, timestamp
FROM
    timestamped_table
CROSS JOIN
    UNNEST(timestamped_table.timestamp_data) AS timestamp
```

Now the only problem I have is that I have to extend these lines from the query:

```
STRUCT<timestamp STRING, timestamp_value INT64>
        ('2020-2-22', _2_22_20),
        ('2020-2-23', _2_23_20)
```

So that they include all the date columns.

I would imagine it to be something like this if I would be extending it by some script(which I think is not the best idea?):

```
STRUCT<timestamp STRING, timestamp_value INT64>
        for column in get_date_columns():
        (timestamp_from_columnname(), column)
```

I think that writing a SQL script/function would be better but I don't know how to start with this exactly

Comment: You need to list the columns explicitly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL and DOES NOT require you to list columns explicitly no matter how many columns you have - 50, 50 or 150 - it should work w/o any changes in below code

```
#standardSQL
SELECT id, Country_Region, 
  STRUCT(
      SPLIT(kv,':')[OFFSET(0)] AS ColumnName, 
      SPLIT(kv,':')[OFFSET(1)] AS Value
  ) AS `Date`
FROM `project.dataset.table` t,
UNNEST(SPLIT(REGEXP_REPLACE(TO_JSON_STRING(t), '[{}"]', ''))) kv
WHERE SPLIT(kv,':')[OFFSET(0)] NOT IN ('id', 'Country_Region')
```

You can test, play with above using dummy data as in below simplified example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 AS id, 'China' AS Country_Region, 12 AS _1_22_20, 34 AS _1_23_20, 54 AS _1_24_20 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS id, 'Italy' AS Country_Region, 22 AS _1_22_20, 44 AS _1_23_20, 64 AS _1_24_20 
)
SELECT id, Country_Region, 
  STRUCT(
      SPLIT(kv,':')[OFFSET(0)] AS ColumnName, 
      SPLIT(kv,':')[OFFSET(1)] AS Value
  ) AS `Date`
FROM `project.dataset.table` t,
UNNEST(SPLIT(REGEXP_REPLACE(TO_JSON_STRING(t), '[{}"]', ''))) kv
WHERE SPLIT(kv,':')[OFFSET(0)] NOT IN ('id', 'Country_Region')
```

with output

```
Row id  Country_Region  Date.ColumnName Date.Value   
1   1   China           _1_22_20        12   
2   1   China           _1_23_20        34   
3   1   China           _1_24_20        54   
4   2   Italy           _1_22_20        22   
5   2   Italy           _1_23_20        44   
6   2   Italy           _1_24_20        64
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to list the columns explicitly.  But you don't need the CTE:

```
SELECT rg.Country_Region, el.timestamp, el.timestamp_value
FROM `username.bq_timeseries_covid19.recovered_global` rg CROSS JOIN
     UNNEST([STRUCT<timestamp STRING, timestamp_value INT64>
             ('2020-2-22', _2_22_20),
             ('2020-2-23', _2_23_20)
            ]) el
WHERE rg.Country_Region = 'China' and
      rg.Province_State = 'Zhejiang';
```

Actually, there are some tricks using JSON and string manipulation, but they are quite hacky and not worth the effort (in my opinion).